# Fetching a large number of images, determining if they are broken or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, ruby-on-rails-4, typhoeus

I have about 600,000 posts in my database, all of which contain a link to an image. In about 1% of these posts, the images are broken (they've been taken down or moved or whatever). I need a fast way to go through all the images and remove posts that have broken images. Here's my code thus far:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  ..unrelated code truncated

  def self.clean_broken_images
    Post.with_image.find_each do |post|
      response = HTTP.get(post.image)
      post.destroy if response == 404
    end
  end

end
```

This works, but as you might expect, it's insanely slow (I haven't actually let it run to completion yet).

Is there a faster way to do it? For example: just return the response header, and delete if it's a 404? Use Typhoeus/Hydra (not sure I could do this for this massive amount of posts)? I should also mention that I am running this with delayed jobs.

Thanks!

Comment: You can just swap `HTTP.get` with `HTTP.head` and see what happens.

Comment: There is no "fast" way to do it. Your code is limited to the speed of your connection, and the connection of the host(s) you're hitting. And, hitting hosts you don't own at full speed is a good way to be banned. Instead, you need to be kind, and do it over time. You *CAN* use something like Hydra and Typhoeus and do it in parallel, allowing them to manage how many requests to allow concurrently. Sort your requests by the domain so Hydra can then keep things throttled to a reasonable level. `head` requests are very fast, but don't deluge the hosts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to proactively remove the Posts from your database?
You could wait until they are requested and use some javascript to load the image(s). If the image can't be found, have the script issue a DELETE request to your server for the appropriate post.

Comment: Good solution! There might be some issues as my API has to have authentication but something to think about.